# How to mark an element as a link so that "Open in new tab" would appear in context menu

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Is there any way to somehow mark an element other than anchor to be a link? My goal is to make some block elements act like `<a href="..."></a>` when clicked with middle or right mouse button. Handling middle button is not a problem - I can just add an event listener and open a new window when `event.button` is equal to `1`.

The only idea that comes to my mind is to wrap an element with `<a href="..."></a>` tag but i have a feeling that it is not an elegant way, especially in angular.

I'm using angular 4 but vanillajs solutions will also be acceptable.

Comment: What is wrong in wrapping it with `<a>` ?

Comment: You could try use any division/tags (by ID or class) and catch the event (onclick) and check for the middle/right mouse click.

Comment: @Venomy for example i cannot wrap `<tr></tr>` with an anchor

Comment: @Luigi no, but you can warp the contents in an `anchor`